# Google cloud error when reading a table via a notebook on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Hi I have a google email account that I use the get into a GCP project, I am trying to read a BigQuery table via a Notebook but when I try to read this table via the notebook I see this error;

```
Access Denied: Table project-name:data_warehouse_us.partnerize_data_clicks: User does not have permission to query table project-name:data_warehouse_us.partnerize_data_clicks. [accessDenied]
Traceback:
```

I go into the IAM settings, and I see the email account I use to access it and it has these 3 roles, `"BigQuery Admin" "BigQuery Data Owner" "BigQuery Job User" do I need to add another role to be able to read/write/delete access to the tables?  or is there another place I need to go to be able to fix this error?

thanks

Comment: Does the Notebook and BigQuery Table exist in the same GCP project?

Comment: @RiccoD Yes they are in the same project

Comment: When you created your Notebook, did you define a specific service account to it? You can check this by going to Vertex AI > Workbench > Choose your notebook > Under "Basic info" tab check the value of "Service account". If you defined a service account, what permissions does it have?

Comment: @RiccoD Thanks!  your solution worked, the email is different than the service account so I added that and now it works, please put it as answer so I can give marked as a correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting as answer confirmed by @JuanLozano. Notebooks uses a service account to authorize requests. While you may set those permission to your email account, you still have to set those permission to the service account that your Notebook uses.

Check the defined service account to the Notebook, and then add the necessary permissions too it.